# Custom CSS in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am creating barcode labels in react like the following:

[image]

These barcodes are created in a grid of 7X2 and the page size is A4. Where the CSS is fixed but I want to make it more user friendly where the user has the option to define the grid i.e. 8x4, 7x3..etc, as well they are able to change the size of the `div.grid-col`

For better understanding:

[image]

Are there any libraries to do so? I am looking for the right direction or approach here

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a code sample

Comment: @RyanLe I am looking for the right approach or libraries available to do such tasks?

Comment: You could do it with Reactjs, state and a bit mix of css